# How to use reflection to call a API by string name?

Tags: reflection, aspnetboilerplate

How to call an API in another AppService by string name?

Example: I have an API as below in MyAppService

```
public class MyAppService : MyAppServiceBase, IMyAppService
    {
        private readonly IRepository<MyEntity> _myEntityRepository;    
        public CommonLookupAppService(IRepository<MyEntity> myEntityRepository)
            {
                 _myEntityRepository = myEntityRepository;            
            }

        public async Task<MyOutput> MyMethod (MyInput input)
            {

            }
    }
```

How to save `MyMethod` as a string into the database and invoke it in another app service? I have many methods like this so I don't want to use `switch case` to call them. I want to save this method assembly name to the database as a string and invoke it when needed. What should I do?

Comment: Is the `AppService` at least known?

Comment: Ya, currently i call to the api directly in a switch case. but i prefer to use reflection instead of a long line of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of:

- `Type.GetType(string)`
- `Type.GetMethod(string)`
- `IIocResolver.ResolveAsDisposable(Type)` — by ABP
- `MethodInfo.Invoke(Object, Object[])`

```cs
// var appServiceName = "MyAppService";
// var methodName = "MyMethod";
// var input = new object[] { new MyInput() };

var appServiceType = Type.GetType(appServiceName);
var method = appServiceType.GetMethod(methodName);

using (var appService = IocResolver.ResolveAsDisposable(appServiceType))
{
    var output = await (Task)method.Invoke(appService.Object, input);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to save "MyAppService" to database as string also?

Comment: Or you can write something like that https://stackoverflow.com/a/14112860/2504064

Comment: @tiennguyen That solves a completely different (sub)problem and requires that you register components manually...

Comment: @aaron because name of app services is generated dynamically, isn't it?

Comment: Component name is generated dynamically and is different with each startup.